# Autofac - Inject custom components as parameters via XML configuration file

Tags: .net, autofac, xml-configuration

With `Castle.Windsor` I was able to define an implementation of a service via XML configuration and pass this implementation as a parameter to other services:

```
<components>
    <component id="service1" service="MyAssembly.IService, MyAssembly" type="MyAssembly.Service1, MyAssembly"/>
    <component id="consumer" type="MyAssembly.Consumer, MyAssembly">
        <parameters>
            <serviceInstatnce>${service1}</serviceInstatnce>
        </parameters>
    </component>
</components>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with `Autofac` XML configuration? I wasn't able to find anything reagarding this in their documentation or tutorials.

Comment: Have you read the [Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html). If so, what specific questions do you have about this subject?

Comment: @Steven, I have and I found it incomplete. There are some features that are missing in the docs, that are only covered in SO answers. My question is quite specific: is it possible to convert the Castle config above to Autofac format?